# AviSynth script with subtitles errors

Tags: ffmpeg, avisynth

Win7

FFmpeg version: 20170223-dcd3418 win32 shared

AVISynth version: 2.6

Calling ffmpeg in a Visual Studio 2015 C# Forms Application and using process.StartInfo.Arguments to pass arguments and read an avs script. Works fine.

The avs script:

```
LoadPlugin("C:\Program Files (x86)\AviSynth 2.5\plugins\VSFilter.dll")

a=ImageSource("01.png").trim(1,24)
b=ImageSource("02.png").trim(1,36)
c=ImageSource("03.png").trim(1,40)
d=ImageSource("04.png").trim(1,72)
e=ImageSource("05.png").trim(1,36)
f=ImageSource("06.png").trim(1,40)
video =  a + b + c + d + e + f

return video
```

I'd like to add subtitles using the avs script but it is not working. Adding the subtitle argument immediately before the "return video" argument results in:

```
subtitle("day 111", align=2, first_frame=0, halo_color=$00FF00FF, text_color=$0000FF00, size=36, last_frame=100)
```

Result error: [avisynth @ 003cdf20] Script error: Invalid arguments to function "subtitle"

Using video.subtitle results in:

```
video.subtitle("day 111", align=2, first_frame=0, halo_color=$00FF00FF, text_color=$0000FF00, size=36, last_frame=100)
```

No error, script completes but no subtitle on output video.

Using subtitle(clip) results in:

```
subtitle(video, "day 111", align=2, first_frame=0, halo_color=$00FF00FF, text_color=$0000FF00, size=36, last_frame=100)
```

The script exits abnormally but there is no error message.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if I can clarify anything.

Comment: This is how *last clip* works in AviSynth. Simply remove `video =  ` and `return video`, use the first `subtitle` code. Alternatively, add `video = ` before the 2nd or 3rd `subtitle` code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, that worked.

```
LoadPlugin("C:\Program Files (x86)\AviSynth 2.5\plugins\VSFilter.dll")

a=ImageSource("01.png").trim(1,24)
b=ImageSource("02.png").trim(1,36)
c=ImageSource("03.png").trim(1,40)
d=ImageSource("04.png").trim(1,72)
e=ImageSource("05.png").trim(1,36)
f=ImageSource("06.png").trim(1,40)

subtitle(a + b + c + d + e + f, "day 111", align=9, first_frame=0, halo_color=$00FF00FF, text_color=$0000FF00, size=36, last_frame=100)
```